# Show that the inverse image of convex set is convex

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, convex-analysis

From S.L Linear Algebra:

> Let $L: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map. Let $S'$ be a convex set in
>   $W$. Let $S$ be the set of all elements $P$ in $V$ such that $L(P)$ is
>   in $S'$. Show that $S$ is convex.
>
> **Remark.** ... The set $S$ in the exercise above is called the **inverse image** of $S'$ under $L$ ...

I'm not completely aware how is inverse image applicable in this case, but I have been able to find few points that might lead to the proof.

---

It can be seen that $S'$ is set of elements $L(P)$ and $L(Q)$ where $P, Q \in S$, such that the line segment $L((1-t)P+tQ))$ where $t \in [0, 1]$, belongs to $S'$ (since $S'$ is a convex set).

Due to the axioms of the linear transformations:

1. $L(X+Y)=L(X)+L(Y)$, for $X, Y \in V$.
2. $cL(X)=L(cX)$, for $X \in V$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$

It can be seen that:

$$L((1-t)P+tQ))=L((1-t)P)+L(tQ)=(1-t)L(P)+tL(q)$$

I believe the result above might correlate with the proof, since $(1-t)$ and $t$ remains unchanged under linear transformation $L$.

---

How can I show that for any two points $P,Q$, $(1-t)P+tQ \in S$? (or more generally, how can I show that $S$ is a convex set?)

Comment: In your statment about $L$, you have $S$ as a subset of $W$ **and** of $V$? Isn't there a typo here? One of them should be $S'$?

Comment: @Somos My apologies, I have been unable to find my typo. $S$ is a subset of $V$, and $S'$ is a subset of $W$.

Comment: Okay, but what is $S'$? You didn't define it before use. Also in the **Remark** I think you switched $S$ and $S'$. Also the title is wrong. You want to ask if the inverse image of convex set is convex.

Comment: @Somos Well I guess I should've paid more attention, **Remark** is taken correctly (in the book), I'm not sure if author has made any mistakes. I'll edit the title right now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P,Q\in S$ and $t\in[0,1]$, then $f\bigl((1-t)P+tQ\bigr)=(1-t)f(P)+tf(Q)\in S'$. Therefore, $(1-t)P+tQ\in S$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the equation that I have defined above is sufficient for the proof? Apologies for ignorant question, but is $S$ convex because its line segments do not change parameters under linear transformation? ($(1-t)$, $t$).

Comment: No. It's because if two points belong to it, then the line segment defined by them is contained in it.